# Filter current user by two values

Tags: filter, multiple-values

Is there any way to set the filter for a web part to be seen by two people? 
for example, in my infopath form, i have a traveler from the active directory, and the creator of the form, who are not always the same. For the moment, i am filtering only by current user  = traveler but i want to allow the created_by also to see the form. When I set two filters on the same web part none can see the form because it works as an "and" meaning that only if traveler = created_by then it can be seen, but if they are different then none of them can see.

Answer (score 0):

Can use Audience Targeting? For this to work you will need have user profile service working.